# Azure pipeline skips DownloadSecureFile task?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, devops, pipeline

I created this `azure-pipelines-regression.yaml` file to run tasks in my Azure pipeline, it has those steps:

```
...... other scripts
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    cd /home/vsts/work/1/s
    npm install --legacy-peer-deps
  displayName: 'npm install'

- script: |
    cd /home/vsts/work/1/s
    dir
  displayName: 'List contents 1'

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: 'Download env file'
  inputs:
    secureFile: '.env.local'

- script: |
    cd /home/vsts/work/1/s
    dir
  displayName: 'List contents 2'
...... other scripts
```

In the pipeline job there are all the steps except the `Download env file` step. I deliberately created the `List contents 1` and `List contents 2` steps and they showed in the job, so I'm sure the code change was pushed. Just the step in the middle was skipped?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `DownloadSecureFile@1` task is not skipped but executed as a pre-job right after the initialization.
[image]

Once downloaded, you can use the `name` value that is set on the task to reference the path to the secure file on the agent machine. For example, if the task is given the name `mySecureFile`, its path can be referenced in the pipeline as `$(mySecureFile.secureFilePath)`.

```
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: mySecureFile
  displayName: 'Download env file'
  inputs:
    secureFile: '{secure file}'

- script: |
    echo The path of my secure file is : $(mySecureFile.secureFilePath)
```

The output is:

[image]